# In HTML 4.0 Transitional jQuery's $(document).height() returns an incorrect value in FireFox and Chrome, but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't switch the DOCTYPE, is there a way to fix this issue in FF and IE?

I have tried

`$(document).height()`, `$(window).height()`, and `$("body").height()`, here's the doctype: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need the following CSS:

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: or remove <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(window).height();
```

the document height is diferent of window height

Comment: I've tried $(document).height(), $(window).height(), and $("body").height(), here's the doctype: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">